# Warhammer Age of Sigmar moving within 3" of enemy models

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

This seems quite an obvious question, but I can't seem to find any answer around the net.

AoS rules state:

> When you move a model in the movement phase, you may not move within
>   3" of any enemy models. Models from your army are friendly models, and
>   models from the opposing army are enemy models.

And also

> Any unit that has charged **or** has models within 3" of an enemy unit can
>   attack with its melee weapons in the combat phase.

So my question is: can I move a unit at exactly 3" from an enemy unit, skip charging, and then just pile in and fight in combat phase?

This kinda sounds awkward as I can imagine an unit running toward an enemy unit, stopping at 3" (because you cannot move it **within** 3") and then just pile in during combat phase. So like I'd just run every time instead of charging as the odds of adding a D6 to your base movement seem better than just moving 2D6.

I think the key of this might be in that **within** keyword: how far from an enemy unit in practice may I end my movement? how far from an enemy unit in practice may I perform a pile in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is pretty clear, if you trim out some of the extra stuff in those quotes:

> you may not move within 3" of any enemy models

and

> has models within 3" of an enemy unit

It seems clear to me that you cannot avoid the charge phase - you can't move within 3", and you can't fight without being within 3".  At the very least, the intent of the rules are clear, and trying to avoid the intent would likely be looked down upon by your opponent.

Comment: So like if I move an unit which is 4" from an enemy unit and has movement 5" I should place it at like 3.1 away so that it won't be within 3"?

Comment: Yep.  That's the idea.